# Build application and Qt from source using cmake

Tags: qt, cmake

I'm trying to set up building an application that uses qt5.6 in a way that both qt and the application are build from source (using the ninja generator, with visual studio compiler on windows and clang on mac).

I'm stuck at find_package(Qt5Core ..) : when Qt is not build yet, it will not be found. And because it's not found, the generate cmake file is not complete.

I think I need a setup where it generates a ninja files that, when build, builds Qt and then regenerates the ninja file (and at this point it would find qt) before continuing the build.

Or any other way in which I can build Qt+application from source, so that if I change something in Qt, it is automatically rebuild.

How should I set up my cmake file(s) to do that?

Comment: Usually, you don't need to rebuild Qt each time. Building of Qt is a very complex process. Are you sure that you need it?

Comment: I don't want to rebuild Qt every time, only whenever it's not there (like the first time), when a file in it changed or when the build instructions or the parts I need change... All of which is exactly what build tools like cmake/ninja do.

Answer (score 3):

You could use CMake's [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/module/ExternalProject.html) command to invoke CMake from within CMake. You can specify dependencies there, so that your application will only be built after Qt has been built.

I happend to have a small example here that uses `ExternalProject_Add` to build a library followed by an application. In that example, CMake for the library and the application is invokved at `make` time.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(cmake_lib
    URL ../cmake_lib
    CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
)

ExternalProject_Add(cmake_app
    DEPENDS cmake_lib
    URL ../cmake_app
    CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
)
```

Comment: That looks like a promising approach, I'll give that a try!

Answer (score 3):

The problem with Qt 5 is that it doesn't use cmake to get built, and thus your ninja build process won't know anything about the internals of Qt unless you tell it everything. E.g. if you change any dependencies of Qt, or if Qt gets partially built, you'd have to add a lot of knowledge to your project's build system to determine whether the Qt build needs to be invoked again. This can be certainly made to work in a "fire and forget" style of build, where the build always starts from scratch, like in a CI system. One quickly runs into serious trouble if the intent is to change Qt itself and re-run the build. Even Qt's own build system has serious trouble with full dependency tracking due to fundamental architectural decisions in qmake.

Qmake-based developer re-builds of Qt suck - and they do to such an extent that I didn't bother contributing to the project since it felt like a penance, where the simplest of changes to one source file would take a minute or more to rebuild on, and any changes to qmake project files would sometimes ballon into multi-minute affairs.

The only solution that I have found that actually works and doesn't make you hate life, the universe and everything, was to reimplement Qt's build *and* configuration system using cmake, so that qmake becomes unnecessary. As a result, a statically linked unity debug build of qtbase takes a couple of minutes with all features enabled - it's pretty zippy and is much faster than the fastest option provided by Qt 5 on Windows for MSVC builds: qmake+jom.

The Qt project endeavored to do this during Qt 6 development, and I believe that they were successful :)